# Why does my .htaccess Not Working in Cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

Please why does rewrite rule to prevent directory listing in my .htaccess file is not working. I want it to show 403 forbidden when i browse a folder that doesn't have an index file.I had (Options -Indexes) in .htaccess but that does not work. I try all my possible best, but i could'nt. Please i need your help.

This is the .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes
```

here is a link to my website : https://www.jeesambo.com.ng
and here the folder https://www.jeesambo.com.ng/index.php/inventory_images

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you have a folder named `index.php`?

Comment: Yes, the `index.php` in there is your problem, that script apparently outputs the directory listing here. The real URL of the folder appears to be just `https://www.jeesambo.com.ng/inventory_images/`, and that shows 403 Forbidden.

Comment: "that script apparently outputs the directory listing here" - the response from `/index.php/inventory_images` is just an unstyled webpage, there is no directory listing. (?)